# さくらVPSを使ったjava-webサーバー構築

Tags: java, centos, tomcat

現在、サクラVPSを借り、CentOS,Apache httpd,Java,Tomcatでwebアプリケーションを公開しようとしています。
以下のURLでアクセスできる状態までもっていきました。

http://○○○.com/tomcat/アプリケーション名/

このURLから「tomcat/アプリケーション名」を消して、
http://○○○.com/
でアクセスできるようにしたいのですが、どのようにすればできるでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

---

追記10/22 -1

---

apache httpdを使用しています。

tomcatのserver.xmlは以下です。

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

---

追記10/22 -2

---

take88さんコメントありがとうございます。
以下に書いてあるものでよいでしょうか？
いろいろと調べなおした結果、ajpというもので連携しているようなのですが、
その設定が以下のようになっていました。

パス：
/etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy_ajp.conf

proxy_ajp.confの内容：
ProxyPass /tomcat/ ajp://localhost:8009/

Comment: 現状の設定に関する説明がないため、どのような設定になっているのか不明なのですが、現状で http://○○○.com/ にアクセスした際に何が表示されますか？

Comment: マイナス投票が投じられていますが、質問内容が分かりにくいのだと思います。スタックオーバーフローでは質問の[ガイドライン](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)がありますので是非参考にして 質問を改善してみてください！そうすれば、見た方からの回答がつきやすくなります。

Comment: take88さんありがとうございます。ガイドライン見てみます！

Comment: ガイドラインとは別に次の2点を追記できますか？ 1. HTTP サーバー(Apache や Nginx など) を使っているのかどうか。 2. Tomcatの `conf/server.xml` の内容

Comment: 追加情報ありがとうございます。Apacheの設定ファイルで Tomcat との連携の設定をしていると思いますが その部分の設定ファイルを掲載できますか？おそらく、Apacheで「/tomcat」をつけていて、Tomcatで「/アプリケーション名/」がついて要ると思うのですが、Apacheの設定が分かれば回答できそうです。

Comment: ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/ とすれば /tomcat は不要になります。これに加えて take88さんの回答(tomcatの設定)をやればいいです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！試してみます！

Answer (score 1):

コメントにも書きましたが、Webサーバの現状の設定に関する説明が無いので、
設定云々での回答はできそうにありません。

ですので、設定にあまり関連しない形での回答を提示します。

URLを変えたいということではなくアクセスしたいという要求を前提とした場合、
Webサーバのドキュメントルートにある`index.html`を下記のように書き換え、
`http://○○○.com/`にアクセスがあった場合に、`/tomcat/アプリケーション名`にリダイレクトさせてしまえば、設定に関係なく実現できます。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/tomcat/アプリケーション名">
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
自分でもサーバーの設定がいまいちわからないままやっているので、どこをどう設定したか思い出せません。笑
できれば、url自体からtomcatの文字を消したいです。

逆に何がわかれば回答できそうか、もしよろしければ教えていただけませんか？

Comment: @take88 さんのコメントにもありますが、
・HTTPサーバを使っているか（使っているのであればその種類）
・tomcatの設定ファイル(server.xml, context.xml)
を提示していただけると、なんらかの回答ができると思います。

Comment: apacheを使用しています。
server.xmlを載せます

Answer (score 1):

まずはTomcatについてだけ回答書きます。

**Tomcatの設定**

`/アプリケーション名/` はコンテキストの `docBase` を変更するか war ファイルの名前を `ROOT.war` に変更すれば 省略できます。

Ex) `http://example.com/tomcat/your_app_name/` → `http://example.com/tomcat/

前者の場合は、次のファイルを作成します。
ファイルの場所：`conf/localhost/Catalina/ROOT.xml`
ファイルの内容：

```
<Context docBase="/path/to/your_app_name.war">
  (略)
</Context>
```

このファイルは context.xml の代わりに読み込まれます。
Databaseの接続設定などが必要でしたら適宜変更してください。

`docBase="/path/to/your_app_name.war"` の部分は war ファイルのパスを書きます。
webapps の下に war を置くとうまく動かないようですので 何処か別の場所に war を置いてください。Tomcatを再起動すると設定が読み込まれます。

後者の場合は、単に war ファイルを mv します。
こちらのほうが簡単ですが warを差し替える度にリネームが必要ですので `ROOT.xml` の方をおすすめします。

```
$ mv your_app_name.war ROOT.war
$ mv ROOT.war Tomcatインストール先/webapps/
```

Comment: 何度も回答ありがとうございます。
難しくて理解するのに少し時間がかかりそうです。
基礎的なことがまだ理解できていないのだと思います。
もしよろしければおすすめの本、webサイトを教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: `ROOT` に関しては特別な扱いので確かに分かりにくいと思います。Tomcatは普及していますし古いソフトウェアですので、ネットの情報もたくさんあります。一つ一つのキーワードで検索すれば、わかりやすいサイトや詳しいサイトが出てきますのでGoogle先生に聞くのが一番良い気がしてます。たとえば Tomcat 入門 で検索してうえから順番に読んでいけばかなりの知識になると思います。もしわからないようでしたらSOに質問を出せばエキスパートの人たちが答えてくれるでしょう。大変でしょうが頑張ってくださいね！

Comment: take88さんありがとうございました！
これから少しづつ勉強していきます！